# I accidentally changed my spawn location, and now I'm lost. How do I find my way back?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was adventuring, and reset my spawn by accident, by interacting with a bed in a random village. I never wrote down the coordinates or followed a compass so I’m completely lost.

I worked really hard, and since I’m on a Nintendo switch it’s confusing with what everyone’s saying? How do I get back home? Is there any commands I can use? I even by accident changed the world spawn to a village?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways you may be able to get back home.

The simplest is to craft a compass which will point you to the world spawn. It's unclear from your post whether you used commands to change the spawn point to a village, or used a bed, but assuming you just used a bed then the compass would point you towards 0,0 which may be enough to help you navigate home once you reach the center of the map.

If you're willing to use commands then I'd recommend temporarily setting your game mode to creative and fly around until you're able to locate your base. In creative mode you'll be faster and able to fly over obstacles. You'll be able to find and identify landmarks more easily from a great altitude.

Answer (score 2):

there are couple of ways you can make your way to your base

1 - craft a compass

crafting a compass which will point to the world spawn

[image]

2 - when you go to settings you should see your seed copy the seed and make a another world with the same seed and if you didnt change the spawn using commands in your orginal world then write your cords and go to the real game and follow that cords

Answer (score 1):

If you did it in Survival, you could make a copy of the world, find where you had as the spawn/your base, and write down the coordinates (using creative to find the base)

Answer (score 0):

`/tp @p 0 ~ 0`
This command will tp you to the world spawn. This should help you then navigate to your base, assuming your base is near the world spawn. And unless your base is underground it should help to make a bunch of maps and explore the area around spawn and look for any unusual blobs of color shaped like your base which should be, ta-da, your base.

If you don't want to use commands you can craft a compass to find world spawn instead. And I still recommend using maps to cover more area as you navigate back and around spawn.